# Variable en string literal C#

Tags: c#

Teniendo este código:

```
` string s ="insert into Administrador values('"+admin.nick+"','"+admin.pass+"','"+admin.nombre+"');";`
```

habría alguna forma de poder hacer algo del estilo de:

```
string s = @"insert into Administador values('admin.nick','admin.pass','admin.nombre';";
```

U obligatoriamente hay que  hacerlo como la primera manera?

Comment: Te invito a que investiges acerca de consultas parametrizadas, es la manera mas correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las [Cadenas Interpoladas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) (necesario C# 6.0):

```
string s =$"insert into Administrador values('{admin.nick}','{admin.pass}','{admin.nombre}')";
```

Pero si estas hablando de consultas sql, lo que debes utilizar es una consulta parametrizada,algo asi como:

```
string s = "insert into Administador values(@nick,@pass,@nombre)"; 
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(s, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@nick", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@nick"].Value = admin.nick;
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@pass"].Value = admin.pass; 
    command.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@nombre"].Value = admin.nombre;

    //ejecutar command ...
}
```

Las consultas parametrizadas permiten evitar las [Inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), asi como solucionan muchos problemas con tipos de datos como las fechas. Se deben usar SIEMPRE.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas en C# se llama [`string` Interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) y es permitido a partir de C#6:

Te permite convertir la consulta que traes:

```
string s ="insert into Administrador values('"+admin.nick+"','"+admin.pass+"','"+admin.nombre+"')
```

En algo como lo siguiente:

```
string s = $"insert into Aministrador values('{admin.nick}', '{admin.pass}', '{admin.nombre}')";
```

Su sintaxis es un literal `$` antes del `string` a asignar o utilizar.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es usar **[string.format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

> Convierte el valor de los objetos a strings basados en los formatos
>   especificados y los inserta en otro string.

Cambiando tu código quedaría así:

```
string s = "insert into Administrador values('{0}','{1}','{2}');";
string s1 = string.Format(s, admin.nick, admin.pass, admin.nombre);
```

Ejemplo:

Suponiendo que los valores de tus variables son las siguientes:

```
admin.nick = "user1";
admin.pass = "pass1";
admin.nombre = "name";
```

El resultado de usar string.Format sería el siguiente:

```
insert into Administrador values('user1','pass1','name');
```